# Access using https redirect-url is denied at Square Connect Authorize

Tags: oauth, square-connect

I am using Square Connect and have a trouble using OAuth API. ([Square Connect OAuth API](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/oauth))

When I set a https redirect-url at the apps page, the endpoint gives me an error response without showing a sign-in page. If I send the same request setting localhost (http), it works fine. Why do I get access-denied? Is there any extra things I need to do for https redirect-url?

1. **Details for https redirect-url (Failed)**
   SSL is self-signed certificate, redirect url is `https://{MY_SERVER}/callback`, and iptables is stopped.

   - **Request**
     `https://squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={MY_APPLICATION_ID}&response_type=code&session=false&state=test`
   - **Callback**
     `https://{MY_SERVER}/callback?state=test&error=access_denied&error_description=Authorization+not+allowed&response_type=code`
2. **Details for http redirect-url (Success)**
   Redirect url is `http://localhost/callback`.

   - **Request**
     `https://squareup.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={MY_APPLICATION_ID}&response_type=code&session=false&state=test`
   - **Callback**
     `http://localhost/callback?state=test&code={MY_CODE}&response_type=code`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am one of the developers of Square Connect.

By default the OAuth flow is disabled for applications which is why you are seeing the "Authorization not allowed" failure. If you wish to enable OAuth flow for your application then you need to contact Square.

Comment: Chris Killpack,  is there any way to communicate with you about a Square Promoted Store